# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have got following code :

```
$('.p1').click(function(){
            var num = 10;
            var count = 0;
            var intv = setInterval(anim,800); 
            function anim(){
                count++;
                num--;
                if(num==0){clearInterval(intv);}
                $(this).hide(function(){
                    $(this).appendTo('#box_'+count);
                }).delay(500).fadeIn();

            }
            anim();
        });
```

i don't know ,if the animation put in function the error appears, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `anim()` function has no `this` context. The click event does have it, but that isn't automatically passed on to your other function. You can set it using `.bind()` and `.call()`:

```
var intv = setInterval(anim.bind(this),800);
...
...
anim.call(this);
```

`.bind()` is used on the `setInterval` line because you want to pass the function whilst having the `this` context set (without calling it). `.call()` is used on the last line because you want to call the function and set the `this` context.

---

Alternatively you can store the `this` context as another variable, making it accessible in the `anim()` function:

```
// in the click event
var element = this;
function anim(){
  count++;
  num--;
  if(num==0){clearInterval(intv);}
    $(element).hide(function(){
    $(element).appendTo('#box_'+count);
  }).delay(500).fadeIn();

}
```